# Fatal Errors After Upgrading to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, paypal, fatal-error, magento-1.9

After updating Magento Community from 1.7 to 1.9 via Magento Connect Manager, my website is now throwing fatal errors. The front end displays this error at the moment:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::getBmlPublisherId() in /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Bml/Banners.php on line 75

The backend allows me to login and under ever tab it shows this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL' in /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php on line 175

---

I tried restoring the app & var directories from a recent backup and it has not fixed the problem. Do I have to do a completely restore all of the directories to fix the issue? I'll be fine with reverting the entire platform back to 1.7 if possible.

Comment: have you installed an extension named BML in 1.7 version, if yes try disabling it and then check.

Comment: In this case, there isn't an extension name BML.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After restoring my app & var directories and deleting all cache & sessions, it wasn't working until I then emptied the minifycache folder as well. I am a bit worried about the stability now because when I log in to MagentoConnect, it is saying that I'm running Magento 1.9 although at the bottom of my backend it shows that I'm running 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Check "community" and "local" pools. It seems you rewrite Config.php in Paypal directory and new magento bml functions not working properly. Check /app/code/local/Mage/Paypal or /app/code/community/Mage/Paypal. If you have any files there try to delete them or copy the new one from /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal and make changes you have in existing files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to 1.9.0.1, deleting app/code/local/Mage/Paypal seems to have solved the problem, the error message has gone from the frontend and I can access payment methods in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

After updating magento to 1.9 I also have the same issue, You can simply disable the **Mage_Paypal** module from backend, You can find this under **System -> Configuration -> Advanced ->Advanced**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to 1.9.3.1. Error indicates:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'METHOD_BML' in /domain_name/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Bml/Banners.php on line 75

When you upgrade to this version, a folder named **Bml** is created under `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/` and this was not present in my old version 1.8 so I compressed this folder for safekeeping, then delete **Bml** folder. It worked for me.